# JavaFX WebView Css transitions not working

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-webview

I am trying to load a local HTML file using the WebView component.
Everything works fine except the CSS transitions.
Here is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML GUI</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>

            input[type=text]{
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                -webkit-transition: width 2s;
                transition: width 2s;
            }

            input[type=text]:focus{
                width: 80%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="welcomeText">Welcome</div>

        <div id="user-block">
            <label>User Name:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>

        <div id="pw-block">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The issue is that whenever I click on the input, the transition happens instantly. The transition time is completely ignored. Am I doing something wrong? Are transitions even supported by the WebView? 
NOTE: I am using JDK 8 (1.8).

**UPDATE: FIXED**
I have managed to fix it by specifying a width for the input...

Comment: Does it help to place the transition properties in the `input[type=text]:focus` block?

Comment: Same issue. I have managed to fix it by specifying a width for the input...